# Sample selection through clustering

Tags: clustering, scikit-learn, sampling

I have a biased set of samples going into a binary classification sklearn pipeline, *white* and *black* samples.

It is easy for me to fetch as many *black* samples as required, while *whites* are a bit harder to get.
I suspect the *black* set is unbalanced and there for I have an incentive to preprocess as many *black* samples as my hardware permits, and pick the most representative samples.

The feature set (after dropping completely invariant features) is about 28k features.

The best approach I came up with is to cluster my *black* samples to a percentage of my white samples. For example say I have 500k *white* samples, I would then cluster the *black* samples to 100k clusters and pick five samples (randomly?) out of each cluster.

My questions are the following:

1. How can I have a transformer that will cluster the samples and mask out the unneeded samples in sklearn? Is there something ready for such tasks or should I build my own transformer based on the clustering algorithm?
2. Can you point at any potential issue with what I plan to do? I think one potential risk here is not clustering the *white* samples, but since I'm not getting enough of those anyway...
3. What clustering algorithms might be a good fit? I'm looking a different clustering algorithms that accept the number of clusters as parameter right now I plan to experiment with most and see which ones work best, but a direction will be appreciated.
4. Additionally, I'd like to read suggestions about other approaches to sample subsampling in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Clustering will be much too expensive for your purpose (most are O(n^2), and the good ones like HAC may even be O(n^3) - you won't be able to run them on 300k instances). Also beware of the prerequisites of the various algorithms - they may not be applicable to your data, or the results may be as bad as random! Also, clustering algorithms may behave rather unpredictable, and will profuce *unbalanced* data sets. It would not be unusual if 99% of your data ends up in the same cluster, while other clusters are almost empty (or even empty!)

I would consider first to **remove all duplicates and maybe near-duplicate records** (ignoring identifiers, of course). These algorithms are much more scalable and tolerate more data types. That may already be enough to achieve your goal of data reduction.